# Java.lang.NullPointerException with Image Drawable in android

Tags: android, image, nullpointerexception, gallery, drawable

I am trying to show a drawable image through which the image(getting Image URL) is dynamically loaded from webservice.

This is my code,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.property_image_adapter);
    Intent intent=getIntent();

    Gallery propertyImageGallery=(Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    intent.getStringExtra("PropertyID");

    PropertyImagesList ImageList=new PropertyImagesList();
    img=ImageList.fetchPropertyImages(intent.getStringExtra("PropertyID"));

    for(int i=0;i<=img.size()-1;i++){

        try {
            Images[i]=drawableFromUrl(img.get(i).Source);//Here I am trying to save the url to the Images variable(eg: www.gggg.com/aa.jpg"). Don't know if this is correct.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
    ImageAdapter=new PropertyImageAdapter(this,Images);
    propertyImageGallery.setAdapter(ImageAdapter);      
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Drawable drawableFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
    Bitmap x;

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("SOME URL APPENDING"+url.trim()).openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return new BitmapDrawable(x);
}
}
```

and this is my ImageAdapter class,

```
public class PropertyImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context ctx;
Drawable[] pics;

public PropertyImageAdapter(Context c,Drawable[] pics) {
    ctx = c; 
    this.pics=pics;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return pics.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {

    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {

    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

    ImageView iView = new ImageView(ctx);
    iView.setImageDrawable(pics[arg0]);
    iView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    iView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
    return iView;
}

}
```

and this is the layout file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
>

 <Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:spacing="10dip"
    >
 </Gallery>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am adding the Image URL's to Images[] variable and setting all the Images in the variable to the Gallery Item in the layout file through the ImageAdapter class.

After this line "Images[i]=drawableFromUrl(img.get(i).Source);" I am getting NullPointerException

This is my logcat,

```
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bu/com.bu.PropertySearchTypes.PropertyImageGallery}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at com.bu.PropertySearchTypes.PropertyImageGallery.onCreate(PropertyImageGallery.java:47)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-19 13:34:29.921: E/AndroidRuntime(16365):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

Please help me out in finding the cause for the exception.

Is this the correct way for Loading Images to Gallery from Web url's. 
  Please correct if any wrong Implementation found in my code.

Any help is appreciated!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call drawableFromUrl() method not from UI Thread. 
Discover this document: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

I advice you to use UniversalImageLoader to load images from internet, look at that library and you won't need to implement your own downloader. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#license